# What is the difference between "fit_transform" and "transform" methods when using "SimpleImputer"?

Tags: machine-learning, python, data-science-model, missing-data, data-imputation

I have following code, I am not able to understand the difference between use of `fit_transform()` and `transform()` method in this case.

In the following code, when I am using `fit_transform(X_valid)` instead of `transform(X_valid)` it gives me different outputs.

```
from sklearn.impute import SimpleImputer

# Imputation
my_imputer = SimpleImputer()
imputed_X_train = pd.DataFrame(my_imputer.fit_transform(X_train))
imputed_X_valid = pd.DataFrame(my_imputer.transform(X_valid))
```

Comment: [a](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.impute.SimpleImputer.html) and [b](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/12321/difference-between-fit-and-fit-transform-in-scikit-learn-models) should help you to understand.

Comment: You can refer this question https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/12321/difference-between-fit-and-fit-transform-in-scikit-learn-models