# Why use fit when already have fit_transform?

Tags: python, scikit-learn

This is a follow up question to: [What's the difference between fit and fit_transform in scikit-learn models?](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/12321/whats-the-difference-between-fit-and-fit-transform-in-scikit-learn-models/92921)

I want to know why should we use `fit` at all when we have `fit_transform` which is much faster than using `fit` and `transform` separately? After all we will always transform the training data after fitting it. Do we have any use of `fit` all by itself?

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate; it's a follow-up.  _Given_ that `fit_transform`=`fit`-then-`transform`, and you usually `fit_transform` training data then `transform` test data, why does `fit` exist as a separate method (or when/why should you use it)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It probably is fairly rare to need to use `fit` and not instead `fit_transform` for a sklearn [transformer](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/glossary.html#term-transformer).  It nevertheless makes sense to keep the method separate: fitting a transformer is learning relevant information about the data, while transforming produces an altered dataset.  Fitting still makes sense for sklearn [predictors](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/glossary.html#term-predictor), and only some of those (particularly clusterers and outlier detectors) provide a combined [`fit_predict`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/glossary.html#term-fit_predict).

I can think of at least one instance where a transformer gets fitted but does not (immediately) transform data, but it is internal.  In `KBinsDiscretizer`, if `encode='onehot'`, then an internal instance of `OneHotEncoder` is created, and at `fit` time for the discretizer, [the encoder is fitted](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/95119c13af77c76e150b753485c662b7c52a41a2/sklearn/preprocessing/_discretization.py#L235) (to dummy data) just to prepare it to transform future data.  Transforming the data given to `KBinsDiscretizer.fit` would be wasteful at this point.

Finally, one comment on your post:

> we have `fit_transform` which is much faster than using `fit` and `transform` separately

In most (but not all) cases, `fit_transform` is literally the same as `fit(X, y).transform(X)`, so this should not be faster.

Answer (score 1):

A relatively late answer, but it is also very convenient to first `fit` all the data then during the deep learning training loop `transform` only the current batch. Otherwise, you have to keep all the arrays in memory, and depending on the amount of data and number of categories, this can become quite huge!